GRPC traffic gets dropped at scale 6000 TPM Even with best practices and channel polling
I am seeing 1-2% grpc Traffic gets dropped even after following best practices.
I am using channel polling of size 10-20, best practices suggested in for polling is we have a unique channel name and even with retry added these numbers did not change.
For channel creation I using bellow code:
This is a java client and there is an AWS grpc loadbalncer in between.
Map<String, Object> customArgs = new HashMap<>();
customArgs.put("channelNumber", String.valueOf(channelNumber));
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(grpcUrl)
.useTransportSecurity()
.defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin")
.enableRetry()
.maxRetryAttempts(6)
.defaultServiceConfig(customArgs)
.build();

And the Error msg I am getting is:
RankingServiceSort EXCEPTION : UNAVAILABLE: unavailableio.grpc.stub.ClientCalls|toStatusRuntimeException|262
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls|getUnchecked|243
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls|blockingUnaryCall|156
proto.RankingServiceGrpc$RankingServiceBlockingStub|sortInventoryData|169
RankingService.RankingGrpcConnector|GetInventoryRanking|80

Please help us we are stuck here from 3-4 months, We are using aws grpc supported ALB in between and these best practices though helped us in reducing DeadLine Acceded issue but service Unavailable cases are not getting reduced. Did now found any detailed documentation as well. We are having 2 instances for this service and both CPU and memory and network bandwidth is not at exhausted, used bellow 5%.
Thanks & Regards,
Pawan Sharma

Channel Pooling aws grpc ALB that helped in reducing Deadline Acceded aces where dealine was 1 sec and server is responding with 1 ms
enabling retry should have reduced service unavailable cases but it did not changed a thing.


UNAVAILABLE: unavailable is a pretty horrible error message. grpc-java does not produce such a message. The errors are being generated by a proxy or the server; it has nothing to do with your client. You aren't configuring retry, so no retries are happening. See https://grpc.io/docs/guides/retry/#retry-configuration

.enableRetry()
.maxRetryAttempts(6) Is not doing the job, this should do it right ?

enableRetry() enables the retry subsystem (which is on by defalut). ``maxRetryAttempts()` puts a limit on what potentially-untrusted service configs can configure. You still need to configure in which circumstances a retry is performed, like UNAVAILABLE.

@EricAnderson I have added bellow retry_service_config still 0.4% cases are failing compared to to old 1% cases {
"methodConfig": [
{
"name": [
{
"service": ""
}
],
  "retryPolicy": {
    "maxAttempts": 5,
    "initialBackoff": "0.1s",
    "maxBackoff": "1.0s",
    "backoffMultiplier": 2,
    "retryableStatusCodes": [
      "UNAVAILABLE"
    ]
  },
  "waitForReady" : true
}

]
}
